# What is Owin.Log log file for?

Tags: federated-authentication

I've setup federated authentication in Sitecore 9 and can log in with my IDP. There is an Owin.Log file in the logging directory but it is always empty. I did some research but was unable to find what this file is for. What needs to be done so something gets logged here?

Comment: have you tried changing the level to something lower than INFO? See Sitecore.Owin.config

Comment: I changed it there to DEBUG but log file is still empty when i log in.